# How to nest WHERE params in Datamapper ORM for Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I am having trouble with a specific query, using Datamapper ORM for Codeigniter. My data model is set up so that I have blog posts, each of which have many categories, users, and tags. I want to fetch blog posts that are related to a specific category, user, or tag, but is **also**  of status "published" or "scheduled."

So in other words, what I want to accomplish is:
`category = General AND (status = published OR status = scheduled)`

In Datamapper ORM I've tried the following syntax (assuming I want posts that are in the category with the name 'General'):

```
$posts->where_related('category', 'name', 'General')
      ->where('status', 'published')
      ->or_where('status', 'scheduled')
      ->get();
```

However, this results in getting posts that are: `(status = published AND category = General) OR status = scheduled`.  Changing around the order of the statements doesn't help either. I can't seem to figure out if there's a Datamapper syntax for nesting the OR conditional in parentheses.

I realize I could write the query in raw SQL, such as:

`SELECT * FROM posts WHERE (status = "published" OR status = "scheduled) AND ...`

...followed by some more complicated JOIN statements, but the whole reason I'm using Datamapper is to make working with relationships easier, so I don't think I should have to write this whole thing out in raw SQL just to nest an OR conditional! I also realize I could use subqueries, but again, I don't think it should be that complicated.

Is there something I'm missing? Some way to organize this query so that I can accomplish it using Datamapper's syntax? It seems like being able to specify the order of operations of the AND/OR statements should be built in somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need parentheses for your where clauses, you need to add them.

See http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/get.html#Query.Grouping for some examples.